# Add array rows from database to one variable

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem on CodeIgniter and MySQL logic maybe. I have two queries, I have executed them, each query has a different array variable and I want to put in one variable.

```
$query1 = $this->db->query("select a from base where id=1");
$query2 = $this->db->query("select b from base where id=2");
$this->data['result'] = $query1->result_array();
$this->data['result'] = $query2->result_array();
```

It's overwritten.

Comment: try this-:  $this->data[] = $query1->result_array();  and in the next line $this->data[] = $query2->result_array();

Answer (score 1):

You are rewriting `$this->data['result']` you need to add as sub array like

```
$this->data['result'][] = $query1->result_array();
$this->data['result'][] = $query2->result_array();
```

so now it will like

```
$this->data['result'][query1_result_array,query2_result_array]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use it like

```
$query = $this->db->query("select a from base where id IN(1,2)");
```

Than use `$this->data['result'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can try an `array_merge` too:

```
$final = array_merge($query1->result_array(),$query1->result_array());
```

This works only provided that `result_array()` returns an index-based array (that is, not an associative array)